# Multiple column sub query not working with cartesian product

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery, cartesian-product

```
SELECT 
   daf.id as affiliate_id,
   daf.name as affiliate_name,
   dal.name as allocation_name,
   dal.id as allocation_id,
   dal.allocation,dal.price
FROM 
     degreeamerica.affiliates daf,degreeamerica.allocations dal
JOIN 
     (select pap.lead_price,pap.live from paul.affiliates_price pap) pafp  
ON (dal.id=pafp.allocation_id and daf.id=pafp.affiliate_id) 
ORDER BY daf.id;
```

Unknown column pafp.allocation_id. I have this column. But its not working. Please help.

Comment: Don't use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` (even if `cross join`).  That will fix your problem.

Comment: you don't have that column in the sub query

Comment: `(select pap.lead_price,pap.live,allocation_id,affiliate_id from paul.affiliates_price pap)` to fix

Comment: Thanks a million cske.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "allocation_id" column is not selected in your sub query.
Add this column in sub queries selected column and check.

```
SELECT 
   daf.id as affiliate_id,
   daf.name as affiliate_name,
   dal.name as allocation_name,
   dal.id as allocation_id,
   dal.allocation,dal.price
FROM 
     degreeamerica.affiliates daf,degreeamerica.allocations dal
JOIN 
     (select pap.lead_price,pap.live, allocation_id from paul.affiliates_price pap) pafp  
ON (dal.id=pafp.allocation_id and daf.id=pafp.affiliate_id) 
ORDER BY daf.id;
```